# I am trying to implement a form within a bootstrap popover but the alignment gets off? Help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a form within a bootstrap popover; but i cannot seem to be able to align them both. The form elements move out side the popover ; the solution should make the popover adjust according to the size of the form elements. Please help.

HTML:

```
<br> <br> <br>
<div class="popover-markup"><a href="#" class="trigger">Popover link</a>
            <div class="head hide"> Events </div>
            <div class="content hide">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                            </label>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn pull-left">Sign in</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover({ 
html : true,
title: function() {
  return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
},
content: function() {
  return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
}
```

});

here's the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6524/

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i found a solution which is basically that i wasn't using the form tags in the body before the form horizontal div. But even if i do that; my fields aren't inline fields. Can anyone suggest a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

Change the form-horizonal to "form-inline" and to be safe you can also add a style to override the popvoer style. I have tried it and its working.

```
 .popover {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: auto;
```